# Why Class C++ can be equal to a variable

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class complex
{
    double re;
    double im;

public:
    complex(): re(0), im(0) {}
    complex(double x) {re = x, im = x;}
    complex(double x, double y) {re=x, im =y;}
    void print() {cout << re << " " << im;}
};

int main()
{
    complex c1;
    double i=2;
    c1 = i;
    c1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why the code in this line compiles.

```
c1 = i;
```

The compiler gives no error(or warning), why?

Comment: dont `using namespace std;` and then use names already present in the std namespace. Thats a recipe for confusing code

Comment: Did you try setting breakpoints in the various constructors for `complex`? That would give you an idea of what is happening (and you could read a good book to learn more).

Comment: Unrelated, but most people would expect `complex(r)` to result in a complex number with no imaginary part; not r + ri, but r + 0i.

Comment: @molbdnilo well, most people who know about complex numbers. I expect *most people* would look at you with a confused expression.

Comment: @user253751 All the more because they don't speak much English. Context, I say, context.

Answer (score 5):

Let's examine what happens in the line.

```
c1 = i;
```

What happens is that `operator=` is called for `class complex`, which, in this case, [is implicitly defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

```cpp
/////////////////////////////////////
//implicit copy assignment operator//
/////////////////////////////////////

complex& operator=(const complex& cmp)
{
    //the default implicit function of this operator is copying every member of cmp into this.
}
```

So it takes `const complex&` as argument, which can be bound to rvalue of type `complex`, then the compiler searches to see if there is a constructor accepting `double` parameter, so the expression is resolved into.

```
c1 = complex(i);
```

Which, obviously, can be executed.

Comment: Thank you for yours responses. It is about a question for C++ certification. I had my response. The implicit constructor is called.

Comment: @Joc380 instead of commenting please mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

`c1 = i` invokes the constructor `complex(double x) {re = x, im = x;}`. If you'd prefer it didn't you can specify the constructor as `explicit`, like so:

`explicit complex(double x) {re = x, im = x;}`

Then the compiler would issue an error @ `c1 = i;`

Answer (score 1):

Because your constructor isn't [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit).

> A constructor with a single non-default parameter (until C++11) that is declared without the function specifier explicit is called a converting constructor.

So having a constructor with a single non-default parameter, such as your `complex(double x)` will enable you to write `complex s = 5.0` and call said constructor.

Comment: I suppose you could also say `complex s = 'A';` or `complex s = true;` which looks *wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

I have added some comments that explain how this program works. When you write `c1 = i;` then a temporary of type `complex` will be created using the converting constructor and then that temporary will be assigned to `c1` using the assignment operator.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class complex
{
   double re;
   double im;

   public:
       complex(): re(0), im(0){}
       //this converting constructor will be used to create a temporary of type complex from variable i
       complex(double x) 
       {
           std::cout<<"single parameter constructor used"<<std::endl;
           re = x;
           im = x;
           
       }
       complex(double x, double y) {re=x, im =y;}
       void print() {cout << re << " " << im;}
      
      //this assignment operator = will be used to assign the temporary(of type complex) created above to variable c1  
       complex& operator=(const complex &rhs)
       {
           std::cout<<"assignment operator used"<<std::endl;
       }
       complex(const complex&)
      {
          std::cout<<"copy constructor used"<<std::endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
    complex c1;
    double i=2;
    c1 = i;//first a temporary of type complex will be created using the converting constructor and then that temporary will be assigned to c1 using the assignment operator=
    c1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to prevent this kind of usage, you can make the converting constructor explicit by adding the keyword `explicit` in front of the converting constructor.